# How to add another filter to TVI default page view?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have the TVI module installed but I wanted to add one more contextual filter

currently: mysite.com/taxonomy/term/[term of tags vocabulary]
[image]

what I want: mysite.com/taxonomy/term/[term of tags vocabulary]/[other term of another vocabulary]

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You're most of the way there by the look of things, change your page settings -> path to `taxonomy/term/%/%`

The second `%` will provide your second contextual filter.